# How to use redirectTo during Sign In with Supabase and Nuxt?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, supabase, nuxt3

This is the code that I use and works:

```
  const redirectTo = `${window.location.origin}${query.redirectTo}`;

  const { error } = await client.auth.signInWithOAuth({
    provider: "google",
    options: {
      redirectTo: "http://localhost:3000/course/",
    },
  });

  if (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};
```

But I want to use the redirectTo variable declared at the top which has the form of:

```
"http://localhost:3000/course/module/module-name/lesson/lesson-name"
```

I also tried to use the entire string, instead of variable and still doesn't work. The user doesn't get authenticated.

I haven't setup and Redirect URL in the Supabase dashboard, because not sure how to enter it. The URL is dynamic, it depends and what Module and Lesson you click on, I want to redirect back to what the user clicked on.

I have also tried on incorrect route like:

```
http://localhost:3000/course/module/module-name
```

In this case, the signing process works, but I get error of route not good.

Anyone has an idea how to fix this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use wildcards in your redirect URL set on your Supabase dashboard.

If you want to redirect the user to `http://localhost:3000/course/module/module-name/lesson/lesson-name`, you could probably set the following in your dashboard:

```
http://localhost:3000/course/module/*/lesson/*
```

You can read more about wild card redirect URL here.
https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/concepts/redirect-urls#redirect-url-examples-with-wildcards